# Hook in meteor to catch all collection method errors

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a collections for `Errors` that displays to the user. I want to insert into this collection whenever a user receives an error, so it can be displayed in a template.

I have a few hooks on my collections that will reject it.

```
// only admins can create and update plans
Plans.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    return Roles.userIsInRoles(userId, 'admin');
  },
  update: function(userId, doc) {
    return Roles.userIsInRoles(userId, 'admin');
  }
});

// Can only have one active plan currently
Plans.deny({
  update: function(userId, doc) {
    var now = new Date();
    Plans.find({
      active: true,
      _id: { $in: doc.planIds },
      dateStart: { $gt: now },
      dateEnd:   { $lt: now }
    }).count() > 0;
  }
});
```

My question is; can I listen to these events and, when rejected, take a particular action on the client and server?

Answer (score 1):

You can insert on the collection via the callback function on whatever `insert/update/remove` you have.

If you want to do to on the server way (sing `Meteor.methdos/Meteor.call`), this is the workflow.

**JS**

```
 //server
    Meteor.method({
     insertDoc:function(doc){
      Plans.insert(doc)
     }
    })
 //Client
 Errors = new Mongo.Collection(null) //client side only
 Meteor.call('insertDoc',{test:doc},function(err,result){
  if(err){
   Error.insert({error:err.reason}) //if there is a error lets insert it
    }
 })
 //and the helper to show the error.
 Template.example.helpers({
  showError:function(){
    return Error.find();
   }
 })
```

**HTML**

```
<template name="example">
  <span>Sorry there was an error: {{error}}</span>
</template>
```

You got the idea.